# Replacing old SSL cert with a new one with IIS

Tags: ssl-certificate, iis-7.5

I purchased a new cert for my web server (GoDaddy) rather than renewed the current one.  In the IIS manager, whenever I do the "Complete certificate request..." and then add my new cert it seems to accept it fine, but when I go off this screen and go back, the cert isn't there? I haven't seen any errors, but I thought it might be because I'm adding a cert with the same friendly name as the old one.  I don't want to remove the old cert quite yet, is there a way around this?

Comment: Did you give the web server the private key?